# Merge Spring data rest links with controller links on same Entity

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-rest, hateoas, spring-hateoas

I would like to combine HATEAOS links to methods on both Controller and Repository.

```
@RepositoryRestController
@ResponseBody
@ExposesResourceFor(Group.class)
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/v2/groups", produces = MediaTypes.HAL_JSON_VALUE)
public class GroupController {

    @Resource
    private GroupService groupService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/external", method = POST)
    public  @ResponseBody   PersistentEntityResource saveExternalGroup(
            @RequestBody Group newGroup,
            PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {

        return assembler.toResource(groupService.saveExternalGroup(newGroup));

    }

}
```

Repository:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(excerptProjection = GroupSummary.class)
public interface GroupDao extends DefaultDao<Group, Long> {

    @NotNull
    List<Group> findByState(@Nullable GroupState state);
...other methods...
```

I would like to achieve to have possibility to go to /api/v2/groups and have there also link to /external. Currently, only links from repository are returned:

```
"_links": {
    "first": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8300/api/v2/groups?page=0&size=20"
    },
    "self": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8300/api/v2/groups"
    },
    "next": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8300/api/v2/groups?page=1&size=20"
    },
    "last": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8300/api/v2/groups?page=1&size=20"
    },
    "profile": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8300/api/v2/profile/groups"
    },
    "search": {
      "href": "http://localhost:8300/api/v2/groups/search"
    }
  },
```

What should I implement to get there all as above plus something like this:

```
"external": {
          "href": "http://localhost:8300/api/v2/groups/external"
        }
```

Or is there problem with that "/external" is POST? If so, please comment and consider this question with "method=GET".

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:

If it's a one-off, you could add the links in the controller method using the `Resource` class.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/external", method = POST)
public  @ResponseBody   PersistentEntityResource saveExternalGroup(
        @RequestBody Group newGroup,
        PersistentEntityResourceAssembler assembler) {

    PersistentEntityResource resource = assembler.toResource(groupService.saveExternalGroup(newGroup));

    // Replace with ControllerLinkBuilder call, or EntityLinks as you see fit.
    resource.add(new Link("http://localhost:8300/api/v2/groups/external","search"));

    return resource;
}
```

Option 2:

If you would like this link to be added to every rendered `Resource<Group>`, then create a `ResourceProcessor` component to add it.

```
@Component
public class GroupResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<Resource<Group>> {

    @Override
    public Resource<Group> process(Resource<Group> groupResource) {

        // Replace with ControllerLinkBuilder call, or EntityLinks as you see fit.
        groupResource.add(new Link("http://localhost:8300/api/v2/groups/external","search"));

        return groupResource;
    }

}
```

Comment: Option 1) This link is generated at the moment method is executed. What I would like to achieve is when I go to /groups there will be link to all DAO methods and all links to Controller. Option 2) I have added processor, but it seems to me it is never called. Then I found out this is problem when using projections (which I do): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33501648/excerpt-projection-and-custom-links-from-resourceprocessor

Comment: @Cipous Ok, option 2 then. If you look in the attached JIRA issue to that question that you linked, you'll see that you can do this, but you'll have to create a `ResourceProcessor<Resource<GroupProjection>>` or whatever your projection is called, to implement that logic. You should still be able to get it to work.

Comment: option with correct projection works for each record, but is not offered in "root" level. By root level I mean if I have no record in database, it offers you "...profile/groups", ".../groups/search" and "self". Is there way to add there another link?